# jQuery selector with a specific ID and a specific attribute value

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to select an element that has **both** a specific ID and a specific attribute value? I'm not finding an option like that in the selector documentation, but I have to imagine it's possible.

For example, an element has ID = foo, and the 'color' attribute set to 'bar'

So far I've got:

```
$('#myID[myattribute='myvalue']')
```

Comment: `ID` values are supposed to be unique on any given page so you would just need `#myID`, nothing more. So if you have duplicate IDs on the page you can just return to sender.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). keep in mind "myattribute" is not a valid attribute name. you should prefix if with `data-*`

```js
let myvalue = 'my-super-value';

$(`#myID[myattribute="${myvalue}"]`).addClass("xxx");

console.log('selector: ', `#myID[myattribute="${myvalue}"]`);
```

```css
.xxx  {
    color: green;
    border: solid 2px orange;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myID" myattribute="my-super-value">my-super-value</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

Html:

```
<p id="data" headers="test">ABC</p>
```

Jquery:

```
alert($('#data[headers="test"]').text());
```